# Linking Parse.com Users to Address Book Contacts

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, social-networking

Hi I am trying to create a friends list similar to the one found in Snapchat for my app.  I am using Parse to save my users.  How do I link the Parse Accounts to the the Address Book Contacts so that you can add friends based on which contacts have an account in my app? I have no idea where to begin.
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: What information are you trying to use to link? Given name? Email address? You don't link anyway, you query and look for matches.

Comment: I was going to use phone numbers since that is what most people have in there contacts. I have taken the user's email but I only use it for password reset.

Comment: So the question is what user details you currently have that you can query against. Asking a user for their contacts phone numbers is pointless I find out have o phone numbers to match against...

Comment: When the user signs up they give a username, their gender, their phone number, their email, and a password. Using this how do I match users to contacts like in snapchat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how snapchat works.

You can request permission to take users contact information. When approved, you should hash the phone numbers and email addresses and upload them to a cloud function which will query your other users for matches. To facilitate that you should store the hash of each users email and phone number (not the originals, unless you need them for something else). You should also use salt when hashing.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try. I have already set up the user permission for the contacts. How should I display the contacts? In a table view?

Comment: I wouldn't display them, just send the (coded) details and search for matches, then you can show the matches (in a table view).